# Autoware NDT_Matching with ouster-128

Tags: ros, localization, navigation, ros-kinetic, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I want to run Autoware NDT_Matching with ouster-128

I am getting a transform error

```
For frame [/os1_lidar]: No transform to fixed frame [world].  TF error: [, when looking up transform from frame [os1_lidar] to frame [world]]
```

I have tested many parameters,

- voxel_grid_filter
- ndt_matching

but it can’t transform [/os1_lidar]  -> [world]  correctly.

Environment: Ubuntu 16.04, ROS Kinetic, Autoware 1.12.0

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/359128/autoware-ndt_matching-with-ouster-128/) by [ken86202](https://answers.ros.org/users/57569/ken86202/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2020-08-10

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Patrick N.](https://answers.ros.org/users/47634/patrick-n./) on 2020-08-10**:
Did you define a transform from map->world? NDT matching should create a transform relative to map frame.

**Comment by [ken86202](https://answers.ros.org/users/57569/ken86202/) on 2020-08-10**:
Yes
I have loaded tf_local.launch (map->world) ,and I have  error

```
For frame [/os1_lidar]: No transform to fixed frame [world].  TF error: [Lookup would require extrapolation into the past.  Requested time 1550.048495240 but the earliest data is at time 1597062760.654010145, when looking up transform from frame [os1_lidar] to frame [world]]
```

**Comment by [Patrick N.](https://answers.ros.org/users/47634/patrick-n./) on 2020-08-10**:
Are you replaying recorded data?

**Comment by [ken86202](https://answers.ros.org/users/57569/ken86202/) on 2020-08-10**:
yes I play rosbag

**Comment by [Patrick N.](https://answers.ros.org/users/47634/patrick-n./) on 2020-08-10**:
Are you using the simulation tab on the gui or setting the use_sim_time rosparam. Seems like some part of your TF tree is using system time and another part using something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

By default, Autoware.AI does not understand the frame `/os1_lidar` because it assumes that the lidar's frame is `/velodyne`. There are a few ways to correct this:

1. Change your Ouster driver to publish the point clouds with the frame `velodyne`. (easiest)
2. Change the code / launch files / configuration files to expect the frame `os1_lidar`. (hardest)
3. Change the `localizer` parameter in `ndt_matching` to `os1_lidar` and publish a static transform between `os1_lidar` and `velodyne` with parameters 0 0 0 0 0 0. (this is unttested but may work)

---

Originally posted by [Josh Whitley](https://answers.ros.org/users/4390/josh-whitley/) with karma: 1766 on 2020-08-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1